# How to change installation directory in squirrel auto update for WPF apps

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, squirrel.windows

I am trying to use [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) to Autoupdate my WPF application. It is installing the application in `%LocalAppData%` folder. I want to change this to `C:\Program Files (x86)` or Path choose by user.

I haven't found any doc related to this on their repo.So how can I ask for installation path while using Squirrel foe WPF application.

Is there any other better mechanism for update my wpf app with out downloading new `.exe` file from webpage manually by user ?.

```
public static async void CheckUpdate()
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("squirrel_temp", @"C:\Program Files (x86)");
        using (var mgr = new UpdateManager(@"C:\Users\jk\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication1\Releases"))
        {
            await mgr.UpdateApp();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A Squirrel app is installed to the directory specified by the `squirrel_temp` environment variable.

You can set this variable to a path in a command prompt prior to calling Update.exe:

```
set squirrel_temp=C:\Program Files (x86)
```

Please refer to the following pull request for more information: https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/pull/846

Asking the user for an installation path while installing is not supported out of the box.

Comment: I have done what you said, but there is no change in installation path. Updated with code. I used `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("squirrel_temp", @"C:\Program Files (x86)");` to set env variable

Comment: Which version of Squirrel are you using? Try the latest (1.5.2).

Comment: Yeah 1.5.2 installed in my project.Is that the correct way I used to set `squirrel_temp`?

Comment: I don't understand where you are doing this. As I mentioned, do it in a command prompt *before* you run Setup.exe.

Comment: Will it consider and work on my client systems if I just do that in my command prompt? How is this gonna work? I am a bit confusing here

Comment: Of course you need to set the environment variable on all client machines that runs Update.exe...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138842/discussion-between-djkp-and-mm8).